# How to run bash script with dialog at startup Centos 7

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have a bash script using dialog which basically just checks the status of certain services and displays it as either up or down. It works fine when I run it while logged in. I can't seem to figure out how to configure CentOS 7 to run this script and dialog when the system boots up. Ideally once CentOS finishes loading all services, instead of display the login prompt it'll just present this dialog to the user. My research seems to keep pointing at creating a service using systemd but I can't seem to find an example to fit my needs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't remember if CentOS uses getty, but if it does, look at the getty services if you want to replace the login prompt. An example I wrote for Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/a/659268/158442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, systemd services shouldn't be running interactive events.  However, you should investigate the [initial-setup-text.service](https://github.com/rhinstaller/initial-setup/blob/master/systemd/initial-setup-text.service), which does something like what you're asking for.

Comment: Do you suggest an alternative solution? My other thought was to create a user with minimal permissions and configure CentOS to autologin with this user account and then load the bash script and dialog this way.

Comment: After thinking through this some more, I decided to just run my script once the user logs in using .profile. Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not using a GUI?  And you want to display these results where the system login banner would normally go, just before the login prompt?

My first thought would be to add a service which depends on all the other services, and which writes to /etc/issue.

But if you want to do this "instead of" the login prompt, how will you log in?

Comment: Without knowing how to make this work, I would assume there would be a way to exit out of my dialog to be able to login or just alt f2 and login from there.

Answer (score 0):

It won't look as pretty as `dialog` but you could write your script to add its results to `/etc/issue` so that it will be displayed immediately before the `login:` prompt.

The info will quickly become obsolete, though, so you should probably run the script from cron as well.

I'd suggest having some unique markers (before and after) your results message so that the cron job can search for and delete the old message before inserting the new.

Alternatively, have an `/etc/issue.head` and/or an `/etc/issue.tail` file to cat together with your results message.

For example:

```
myprog > /etc/issue.results
cat /etc/issue.head /etc/issue.results /etc/issue.tail > /etc/issue
```

Comment: BTW, most modern `getty` programs support ANSI escape sequences in /etc/issue and there are various tools (e.g. `boxes`) to generate nicely formatted boxed text etc from plain text input.